# Assign specific color to specific segment in D3 Pie Chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, ember.js

I have built a pie/doughnut chart using D3js (v4) as an Ember component and I am trying to have segments with specific labels be filled with a specific color but it is proving difficult.

To color the charts I have the following code:

```
marc = arc().outerRadius(radius - 10).innerRadius(radius - donutwidth),
color = scaleOrdinal().range(['#49b6d6', '#f59c1a', '#ff5b57',  '#00acac',]),

gEnter.append("path")
      .attr("d", marc)
      .attr("fill", (d, i) => {
        return color(i);
      })
```

The above works fine and fills the arcs with the selected colors but not the color I want per arc. The index of the array is consistent so I tried to simply re-arrange the order of the colors with no effect.

I also tried using an if statement based on the index like:

```
gEnter.append("path")
          .attr("d", marc)
          .attr("fill", (d, i) => {
            if (i === 0 { return color([0]) }
       })
```

This does fill in the segment which is index 0 but not with the selected color from the list. Changing the number in color([0]) actually produces no change at all. This is also true if I try to use a conditional based on the string of the Label instead of the index of the array.

**EDIT**

As part of the Ember Computed Property that formats data for the chart, the data is re-ordered so that each label is presented in the same order every time. THe computed property is as follows:

```
//takes the ember model 'referralsource' and groups it as needed   
sourceData: groupBy('referralsource', 'label'),

//ember computed property that provides data to chart
  pieData: Ember.computed('sourceData', function() {

    let objs = this.get('sourceData')
    let sortedObjs = _.sortBy(objs, 'value')
    let newArray = []

    sortedObjs.forEach(function(x) {
      let newLabel = x.value
      let count = x.items.length
      let newData = {
        label: newLabel,
        count: count
      }
      newArray.push(newData)
    })
    return newArray
  }),
```

Comment: Do you sort or reorder anything in creating your donut - if you log d in the the function to select fill does each datum correspond to the proper index?

Comment: Hi Andrew, I've edited the question above. I do sort the objects as part of my attempts to get them listed in a consistent order - previously they could be returned in any order which I thought was causing problems with the colors per segment changing. When I log (i, d) I can see that the value of (i) does not always match the value of index in the individual object. In fact, the only value that does match is the only one that is colored when I follow Thiago's suggestion about adding the .domain

Answer (score 1):

in your first example, try changing this:

```
color = scaleOrdinal().range(['#49b6d6', '#f59c1a', '#ff5b57',       '#00acac',]),
```

for this:

```
color = scaleOrdinal().range([0,4]),
color.domain(['#49b6d6', '#f59c1a', '#ff5b57', '#00acac']),
```

the range you use to indicate the size of your scale (in this case 4 because you put 4 colors) and the domain specifies what things are in each position of that scale

Comment: I see what you are getting at. I changed the line to `color = scaleOrdinal().range([0, 4]).domain(['#f59c1a','#49b6d6', '#ff5b57', '#00acac']),` and this actually stopped coloring the arcs. They still draw but are all black. Do I need to change anything else?

Comment: you are putting d3.scaleOrdinal... ? or just scaleOrdinal?

Comment: Its an Ember component so D3 is imported as a module rather than called via `d3.` thanks to [ember-d3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-d3)

Answer (score 1):

If your labels are the same each time (or draw from the same pool of options), you can specify a specific domain. In an ordinal scale, the domain :

> sets the domain to the specified array of values. The first element in
>   domain will be mapped to the first element in the range, the second
>   domain value to the second range value, and so on ([from the API documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#ordinal_domain)).

By setting the domain equal to an array that contains each possible label option, you can easily assign a color to each label. The example below has five possible labels, the first row uses the opposite data array order as the second row, the third row uses a random order with duplicates. All three rows associate each datum with a specific color consistently:

```js
var labels = ["redData","blueData","orangeData","pinkData","greenData"];

var colors = ["crimson","steelblue","orange","lightsalmon","lawngreen"];

var scale = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(labels)  // input values
  .range(colors);  // output values
  
var svg = d3.select("svg");

// initial order
svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(labels)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cy",40)
  .attr("cx", function(d,i) { return i * 40+ 20; })
  .attr("r",15)
  .attr("fill",function(d) { return scale(d); });
  
// reverse order
svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(labels.reverse())
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cy",80)
  .attr("cx", function(d,i) { return i * 40+ 20; })
  .attr("r",15)
  .attr("fill",function(d) { return scale(d); });

// random labels
svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(["blueData","blueData","redData","orangeData","blueData"])
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cy",120)
  .attr("cx", function(d,i) { return i * 40+ 20; })
  .attr("r",15)
  .attr("fill",function(d) { return scale(d); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>


<svg width="600" height="400"></svg>
```